# MPXJ library with VB6 , is it possible?

Tags: vba, vb.net, vb6, ms-project, mpxj

I'm trying to communicate my application VB6 (et VBA) with MS Project 2007 so I would like to use the MPXJ library. The problem is that I dont know if it's possible to use these .net libraries with my VB6 application. I cant add the .dll directly

How could I do this, ideas? I can't migrate my code to vb.net

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pleased to say that MPXJ can be used via COM. You'll need to download version 4.5.0 from SourceForge. In the `lib.net` directory you'll find the DLLs and TLBs you'll need. You will need to use `regasm` to register the assemblies for use with COM. There are some brief notes [here](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/howto-com.html) on working with MPXJ via COM.

You may find the notes [here](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/howto-dotnet.html) useful as they discuss the three different flavours of `mpxj.dll` that are shipped, and MPXJ's dependencies.

I'd be happy to update the documentation on working with MPXJ via COM in the light of your experience!

Comment: I registered the dlls via regasm but I had to add \tlb \codebase to the bat instructions. Now VB6 recognize the lirary and I can read a document. Anyway I having problems with adding task durations for example, I dont know how to set the duration value or type (hour, day, etc).